# Docker on Windows - port locked

Tags: windows, docker, go

I recently experienced an error while I was trying to test locally my Golang API.

My API was exposed on the port 8080:

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
```

My final docker file expose the API on the same port:

```
FROM scratch

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./fooAPI.exe /app/fooapi
COPY ./cmd/fooAPI/conf.json /app

# tell we are exposing our service on port 8080
EXPOSE 8080

# run it!
CMD ["./fooapi"]
```

When I was trying to run my docker image, I had the following error message:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint fooapi (f6d5bed281ad1e8c1c56770cc1c05e3b5a7f8a05abd8265ae3a4007eeb3ff895): 
Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:8080:tcp:172.17.0.2:8080: input/output error
```

Event after the deletion of the previous containers by using the command below:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Comment: Could it be that you are still running your go code locally? That would block the port.

Comment: @PassKit, I forgot to precise this in my post then, I have updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker on Windows sometimes lock your ports, even after the deletion of your container, during an undetermined duration.

The simplest thing you have to do is to restart docker and the port are no longer locked.

Comment: This does not work if your host crashed.  Docker will leave the port locked and the only way to unlock is to uninstall Docker, restart, restart again and then the port is no longer locked.  You can then reinstall Docker.

Comment: Thanks @RichardCrane. I'm afraid to see that such a problem is still there almost one year later ! I definitely recommend Ubuntu as a more stable environment and a smooth transition from Windows.